# Custom progressbar on a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-progressbar

I want to show a custom progress a notification on an android device that has a design like the following image.
[notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf07K.png)
I have tried using seekbar to achieve the effect, but it seems seekbars cannot be used on a notification.

What i want to achieve with a progress bar is to have the thumbnail move along with the progress.

Comment: try this http://tjkannan.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-notification-with-progress-bar.html
Are you familiar with RemoteView ?

Comment: yes, i'm using remote view, and i'm already showing and updating the progressbar. the issue comes when i want to have an image to act like the thumb of the seekbar and move along with the progressbar.

Comment: Do you want your user actually move the thumb? Or its just a ui ornament?

Comment: just as an ornament, i dont want the user to be able to move it since its to show the progress of the trip.

Comment: then why not a custom seekbar? either way user isn't gonna be able to move it, right?

Comment: can you give me an example? y tried to put a seekbar on the notification widget via remoteview and it gave me a lot of troubles.